# Existence of grandchild nodes and iterating over their values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following structure:

```
League

----Clubs

---------Club

-------------Players

--------------------Player

--------------------------FirstName

--------------------------Surname etc

--------------------Player

--------------------------FirstName

--------------------------Surname etc

---------Club

-------------Players

--------------------Player

--------------------------FirstName

--------------------------Surname etc

--------------------Player

--------------------------FirstName

--------------------------Surname etc
```

Anyhow - I would like to get the names of all the players in my xslt conversion (I'm using a Biztalk Mapper so must stick to XSLT1 - I prefer to use inline XSLT than the mapper tools as the XML I'm converting to expects a nil attribute in the situation where there are no players at a club (there is one club in this situation, but also I'm keeping to that for future proofing)

Here's a rough sample of what I've tried:

```
    <xsl:template name="PlayerNames">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:PlayersInLeague">
<xsl:element name="ns0:Team>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="current()/*[local-name()='Players']/*[local-name()='Player']">
    <xsl:for-each select="current()/*[local-name()='Players']/*[local-name()='Player']">
        <xsl:element name="ns0:Player"><xsl:value-of select="current()/*[local-name()='FirstName']"/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">true</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

I would like an output along these lines:

PlayersInLeague

----Team

------Fred

------David

----Team xsi:nil=true

----Team

------Alex

------Tom

from an input of

```
<league>
<clubs>
<club name="London">
<players>
<player>
<firstname>fred</firstname>
</player>
<player>
<firstname>david</firstname>
</player>
</players>
</club>
<club name="Madrid">
<players/>
</club>
<club name="Amsterdam">
<players>
<player>
<firstname>Alex</firstname>
</player>
<player>
<firstname>Tom</firstname>
</player>
</players>
</club>
</clubs>
</league>
```

I'm not entirely sure on what the current() command is doing, and i've gone and changed this so many times I can't see how to correct it now - can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT, you usually want to use pattern matching to distinguish different cases. Here, you can make two templates - one for empty club and the other for regular clubs.

It's verbose, but it's actually very clear once you forget for-loops.

**EDIT :** Now, I see it would make more sense if I organised the templates in reverse. So, please read the stylesheet from the bottom to top. Sorry. ;-)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <xsl:template match="player"> <!-- only display firstname contents -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="firstname"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="club"> <!-- default club template -->
        <team>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </team>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="club[not(players/player)]"> <!-- empty club template -->
        <team>
            <xsl:attribute name="nil" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</xsl:attribute>
        </team>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/"> <!-- entry template -->
        <PlayersInLeague>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </PlayersInLeague>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! What I'm confused over however, how does this: <xsl:apply-templates select="firstname"/> 
 know I want <firstname>Fred</firstname> for example? Or do I have to add a seperate template? Never really dealt much with templates etc

Comment: <xsl:apply-templates select="firstname"/> will by default include all text found under firstname element (but no elements). xsl:copy-of should copy the whole subtree as it is.

Comment: XSLT is based on templates. They are applied when the engine goes through the input XML (when they match current node). So it is the input document who really controls the execution.

Comment: Thank you :) worked (once I'd added names to the templates) :)